# Xamarin questions

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have a few questions and I'm hoping some people could explain it a bit more.

Recently Xamarin has been released to the public for free and you're able to download/install it for free.

Let me say first that I have Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015 installed on my computer.
I have succesfully installed Xamarin and the Java/Androids SDKs and got it running.

But now I have the following 'problems':

1. When opening a new Xamarin Forms project I get the following message:

   "A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'Projectname.Windows'. This project requires a Visual Studio update to load. Right-click on the project and choose "Download Update"."

   Is this because of my OS?
2. When opening the new project, the 'ProjectName.UWP (Universal Windows)' subproject always give errormessages on everthing.

   Reason?
3. If I want to run the .IOS subproject, is the only way by connection a IOS device? Is there no emulator for example an Iphone?

Thank you.

Comment: just upgrade your os latest this will resolve the proplem or otherwise contact support for xamarin

Comment: I had the same problem with number 1&2. I upgraded to windows 10 and after that downloaded the upgrades for xamarin and that did the trick for me.  as far as 3 goes then yes you do need an apple device.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's possible that you don't have the SDK / tooling installed for Windows Phone, so you will have to download the update as described in the error message - this should resolve the problem.
2. What error messages are you receiving?
3. You need to connect to a Mac over the network which will allow you to build and debug your apps. You can deploy apps to the iOS Simulator on your Mac, or to an iOS device connected to your Mac, from Visual Studio. For more information on using Xamarin.iOS with Visual Studio, I would suggest the following guide: [Introduction to Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/)

Comment: I have the newest Windows 10 SDK installed, so probably thats why. I still have Windows7. But I'll upgrade it to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions.

**1.** You should check you updates of the Visual Studio. There are a possibilities that the supporting packages can't locate. The error says that you need to download the updates. Nah, it's not about your OS. If you are done installing the visual studio, then your IDE is working properly. The problem persist is whenever you are lack of updates and packages in the give project.

**2.** The error could be your pc has no windows emulator to support the UWP to run properly. If you have one, uninstall it and install again.

**3.** You can use emulator, iOS Emulator but you still need a mac. There's a agreement between microsoft and mac regarding this thing. So far, until now, you can't run iOS simulator in Windows without Mac devices with XCODE

I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your Questions
 1. it may be a visual studio update issue, try with latest.
 2. i think UWP projects are not supporting with windows 7 OS(correct me if i am wrong), and also try with shared project structure,because portable has some problems with  windows 7.
 3. Yes currently there is no iOS emulator for Visual studio, if you want to run your app on ios simulator you have to connect your visual studio to Mac machine and then you can run.
 Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:
1- you might need to upgrade to windows 10. I have solved many issues when I upgraded to Windows 10. VS 2017 works very well with win10.

2- I would definitely recommend downloading the Visual Studio emulator which is a dedicated standalone application that has many emulators. It's much faster and reliable than android emulator. Also it has iPhone and windows emulator too.

3- in order to be able to use iPhone emulator, you must either do:
A) have a Mac device in the network to be able to connect VS with it. And it must have xcode installed on it.

B) you can also do a vmware virtual machine on any windows device and install on it xcode.

For detailed explanation on how tondo the above you can find them on YouTube.

Hope you have more luck.